# Invalid CSS after " ": expected 1 selector or at-rule, Vue Js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, sass, sass-loader

I was coding in my sass file but failed to compiled it in App.Vue
It shows the Following Error . Installed Sass , sass-loader packages .

```
Invalid CSS after " ": expected 1 selector or at-rule, was "{    $primary: #1ec"
      in F:\Vue Projects\vue-app-two\src\mq.sass (line 1, column 1)
```

I am beginner in all this so if you need more info just ask .

Here is the sass file .

```
$primary: #1ec !default

$tablet: 769px !default

$desktop: 1000px !default

$widescreen: 1192px !default

$fullhd: 1384px !default

=mobile
    @media screen and (max-width: $tablet - 1px)
        @content

=tablet
    @media screen and (max-width: $tablet),print
        @content

=tablet-only
    @media screen and (max-width: $tablet) and (max-width: $desktop -1px)
        @content

=desktop
    @media screen and (max-width: $desktop)
        @content

=desktop-only
    @media screen and (max-width: $desktop) and (max-width: $widescreen -1px)
        @content
```

Comment: The issue here is most likely that `{` you see at the beginning of the string that causes the issue. Since I don't see it in your code here, I am assuming that it appears where you include this file.

Comment: So can you suggest me what will be the next step . I have done the recommended changes but the output is still same .
I have included this file as
@import '../mq';

Comment: Can you share the complete sass/scss file where you import this file? If it is included in the style section of a component, please add the style section to your answer instead.

Comment: I included it in App.vue
This is the Style Section

<style lang="saas">
import "../node_modules/bulma/bulma.sass";
import "mq"; // since it is in on my root and App.vue is also on root
</style>